# Swift dynamic prototype row height

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview

I'm having a problem with storyboard at the moment in Xcode 6.3. I made 3 prototype cells and am able to return them in the right format meaning 1 of the first type 3 of the second type and 1 of the last type per group.

However the 3 rows of the second prototype need a different size that I would like to be hardcoded so no dynamic size just bigger than default.

I did this in the storyboard but for some reason it keeps returning the default size for a row. I have a custom `TableViewController` and `TableViewCell` subclasses.

Please help me out how to return the custom height, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be specific about rows... By referring `indexPath`, This row is going to be this size!
Try something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   var row = indexPath.row

   switch row {
     case 0...1: return 35
     case 2...4: return 65
     case 5: return 100
     default: return 150
   }
}
```